# Paging in SQL extremely slow when using row number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data in batches. This one goes pretty fast:

```
select top 10 * from Table1 where (subject like '%Recap%' or subject like '% CP %') and Body like '%Details:%' and  ToAddr like '%xx@hotmail.com%'
```

Now when trying to get that data in batches it takes around two minutes. The query is extremely:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
 select*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as row from Table1 where (subject like '%Recap%' or subject like '% CP %') and Body like '%Details:%' and  ToAddr like '%xx@hotmail.com%'
 ) a WHERE a.row > 10 and a.row <= 20 ​
```

Am I getting the batches in a wrong way?

---

Just discovered even this is pretty slow:

```
select top 10 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row from Table1 where (subject like '%Recap%' or subject like '% CP %') and Body like '%Details:%' and  ToAddr like '%xxx%'​
```

Comment: Have you tried `OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: Can you use that with an where clause?

Comment: Put it after the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: TOP without an ORDER BY returns first (random) found 10 rows. When you add ORDER BY to get the following 10 rows, much more work has to be done to sort the result.

Comment: Worked. Not super fast but proeprly bad dimenzioned DB. Can you post an answer, and thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have an index on name? That's need for efficient pagination of an ordered result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the end, after the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Also, take some time and read https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments.  You could try something like this

```
declare
  @pagesize     int=10,
  @pagenumber   int=2;

select * 
from Table1 
where (subject like '%Recap%' or subject like '% CP %') 
     and Body like '%Details:%' 
     and  ToAddr like '%xx@hotmail.com%'
order by [name]
offset @pagesize * (@pagenumber - 1) rows
fetch next @pagesize rows only;
```